# Rails 3.2 and bootstrap - how do I create a inline form?

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to assign a form-inline class to the following form in rails

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">

    <%= form_for @annual do |f| class="form-inline" %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>

      <%= f.label :a %>
      <%= f.text_field :a class="input-small" placeholder="a" %>

      <%= f.label :b %>
      <%= f.text_field :b class="input-small" placeholder="b" %>
      .
      .
      .
```

The bootstrap documentation for inline forms is here:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html?#forms

When I try the above approach for the classes and placeholders, I get an error. What is the correct way to do this in rails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution via google, for those interested it is:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span6 offset3">

  <%= form_for @annual, {:class => "form-inline"} do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>

    <%= f.text_field :a, :class=> "input-small", :placeholder=>"a" %>

    <%= f.text_field :b, :class=> "input-small", :placeholder=>"b" %>
```

Answer (score 7):

In case this helps someone, I had to do `:html => {:class -> "form-inline"}` for it to add the css class in Rails 4.

Comment: Great! But you mean to say `=>` I'm sure